# Remove woocommerce default checkout form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, woocommerce, checkout

Since I'm not very skilled in php, I've tried to remove thru css the woocommerce default form (so I could use my custom fields).
The problem is that woocommerce is still givin me error at the end of checkout because some fileds are required in the default form.

I've already added this code to ignore default checkout form, added an addon (N-media), form looks perfect but on checkout does nothin.

```
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
unset($fields['billing']['billing_first_name']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_1']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_country']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_state']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_phone']);
unset($fields['order']['order_comments']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_address_2']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_postcode']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_company']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_last_name']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_email']);
unset($fields['billing']['billing_city']);
return $fields;
```

}

I wish to remove it for good and keep on using my custom form.

Thank you in advice.

Comment: why dont you try Customizing checkout fields using actions and filters?
Woocommerce Documentation link 

http://docs.woothemes.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/

Comment: find how to unset all checkout fields and add new form to the checkout. searching is your best friend :)

Comment: please do not add the php code in comments , please edit your question with the new source code which you are using. its very messy.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to be messy;)

Answer (score 0):

The [official documentation here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/tutorial-customising-checkout-fields-using-actions-and-filters/) states that you can override the core fields to make them your own.

Example:

```
// Hook in
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields' , 'custom_override_checkout_fields' );

// Our hooked in function - $fields is passed via the filter!
function custom_override_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
     $fields['order']['order_comments']['placeholder'] = 'My new placeholder';
     return $fields;
}
```